# Parsing BBCode on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing, bbcode

I am in a spot here trying to **parse BBCode upon a AJAX success** : item.message object. I am using jQuery 1.11. I have tried passing the var result in place of item.message, and only shows the [object] errors. I have tried wrapping item.message with XBBCODE and same thing.

Im not sure what to do, the script is great otherwise. We must parse bbcode to HTML or a method that can be managed PHP-side, but I don't think this is possible over JSON data.

Currently this is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/shoutbox.php",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                var html_to_append = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    // Object array repeated - not working
                    var result = XBBCODE.process({
                    text: 'item.message',
                    removeMisalignedTags: false,
                    addInLineBreaks: false
                    });
                    /*
                    currentPost = jQuery(this);
                    postHTML = bbcodeToHTML(currentPost.html());
                    currentPost.html(postHTML);
                    */
                    html_to_append +=
                        '<div class="shoutbox-container"><span class="shoutDate">' +
                        jQuery.timeago(item.date) +
                        ' <span style="color:#b3b3b3">ago</span></span><span class="shoutUser"><img src="' +
                        item.avatar +
                        '" class="shout-avatar" /></span><span class="shoutText">' +
                        item.message +
                        '</span></div><br>';
                });
                $("#shoutbox").html(html_to_append);
                $(".shoutbox-container").filter(function () {
                    return $(this).children().length == 3;
                }).filter(':odd').addClass('shoutbox_alt');
                $(".shoutbox-container").each(function () {
                    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, this.rowSpan - 1).addClass('shoutbox_alt');
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

As you see, I'm trying to make use of the following javascript:

https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser

I've followed the instructions exactly, before moving into the JS above with no success either way. I get this:

**[object][Object]**

For each iteration of the message object coming back (its a custom AJAX shoutbox).

Commented, you can see another method I have tried to no success. Any help is appreciated!

**Update: Working**

Thank you, **Quiet Nguyen** for the suggestion for replacing **item.message** with **result.html** and updating **text:** object

Comment: In `XBBCODE.process` lines, replace `text: 'item.message',` with `text: item.message,` (no quotes). In `html_to_append`, try replacing `item.message` with `result.html`.

Comment: working like a charm! Will update post, thank you